# How do I solve my BuildTime errors in my RN iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add react native google sign in to my iOS app but it will not build due to the many error that I'm getting. I followed the documentation on a variety of sample apps apart from my current one and continue to get a variety of errors. All the suggestions that I tried from research just don't seems to work. Here is a sample file:

**PodfileImage**

[image: ScreenShot]

```
platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"

target 'ExampleApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 6.2.2'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :production => production,
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'BarberAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
 
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

**Buildtime error screen**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/issues/718

Comment: thanks, Its a little bit different though but it helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I did not added the firebase package provided in the firebase console when creating the new project. I used YouTube videos that posted a year or two ago however changes have been made on the firebase application